# How to countByKey in JavaPairDStream without foreachRDD?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

This might be a very trivial question, but I just don't know what is wrong.

I have a JavaPairDStream,and for each batch interval I want to get the number of keys in my RDD within the stream, so that I can use this number later in the application.

The problem is, I can get the number of keys by doing:

```
streamGiveKey.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> stringStringJavaPairRDD) throws Exception {
            int a= stringStringJavaPairRDD.countByKey().size();
            countPartitions=a;

            System.out.print(a + "\r\n");
            return null;
        }
    });

JavaPairDStream<String,Iterable<String>>groupingEachBoilerValues= streamGiveKey.groupByKey(countPartitions);
```

In which `countPartitions` is a global variable that stores the number of keys for one batch interval.

The problem is, the application never reaches `groupingEachBoilerValues`, it just keeps printing inside the forEachRDD in an endless cycle.

Is there another way for me to do this?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a global count in the driver. Here

```
long globalCount = 0L;

 .. foreachRDD( 
      ..  globalCount += rdd.count();
```

This globalCount variable will reside in the driver and will keep being updated after every batch.

**Update** Skeptics ahoy!  The above code is specific to *streaming*. I am well aware it would not work in standard non-streaming RDD code.

I have created test code encompassing the above approach and the counter works fine. Will post this code in a few minutes.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
var globalCount = 0L
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(4))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 19999)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.print()
lines.count().foreachRDD(rdd => { globalCount += rdd.count; println(globalCount) } )
ssc.start
ssc.awaitTermination
```

Here it is running

```
scala> ssc.awaitTermination
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1466366660000 ms
-------------------------------------------

1
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1466366664000 ms
-------------------------------------------

2
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1466366668000 ms
-------------------------------------------

3
```

Here is a tiny data generator program to test with:

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
case class ClientThread(sock: Socket) {
  new Thread() {
   override def run() {
      val bos = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream)
      while (true) {
          bos.write(s"Hello there it is ${new java.util.Date().toString}\n".getBytes)
          Thread.sleep(3000)
      }
   }
   }.start
 }
val ssock = new ServerSocket(19999)
while (true) {
  val sock =  ssock.accept()
  ClientThread(sock)
 }
```

Comment: If I declare this variable inside the Main() method it is not recognized inside foreachRDD. Should I declare it as a global variable?

Comment: The same thing happens. I declared `private static long globalCount=0L`, replaced it instead of countPartitions and it didn't work.

Comment: That won't work when you deploy your code on a spark cluster. It only works when distributed tasks will run on the same jvm instance.

Comment: @YoYo  It *does* work *for streaming*.  I have it working now - will be placing the code.

Comment: Even if it would work, it does not have the basic protection mechanisms for concurrent access to the variable. You will be able to get it to compile, and even to run, but most likely you will see the global variable as unchanged, unless you are executing it in a local context.

Comment: Retract that - you are using `forEachRDD` (not `forEachPartition` as I first assumed) - that does work already within the local context of the driver, and you should be fine as you indicated. I can't test though.

Comment: @YoYo  Thanks for re-reading this.   I provided the code. Will add the tiny data generator (on port 19999) in a moment.

Comment: @manuelmourato  Please take a look at the updated answer that includes working code and a data generator test program.

Comment: @javadba, thank you very much for your examples. However the problem is still the same: I am running my Spark Streaming Context within the main() method. If I declare `private static long globalCount=0L` outside of the main, the result is exactly the same as the one I mentioned in my question. If I declare it inside the main(), it doesn't get recognized inside the Function within the foreach

Comment: Please note: I do not want a counter variable for all elements in an rdd, I want a counter for each key in the RDD. Maybe this is redundant, but I thought I would mention it